# what does Error “Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)” mean in delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

i got this error, and how can i solve this error? I addd this code bellow in AppDelegate to make CRUD App and i don't know to solved it.

```
let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "CoreDataExample", withExtension: "momd")!
```

my reference from here ..http://codewithchris.com/iphone-app-connect-to-mysql-database/

cause i use XCode 8 and in this tutorial use xcode 7.

Comment: In this case it means you don't actually have a file named `CoreDataExample.momd` in your app's resource bundle.