# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION Error in AppDelegate (Bundle.main.url?)

Tags: ios, bundle, appdelegate, exc-bad-instruction

I am having a problem within my AppDelegate but can't find the mistake, I checked the bundle identifier but it still doesn't work, there is my code :

```
lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
    let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1] as NSURL
}()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "koalak", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)!
}()
```

A screenshot of the Error I get :

[image: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION Error Screenshot]

[image]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40393315/what-does-error-thread-1exc-bad-instruction-code-exc-i386-invop-subcode-0x0 Are you in the same class or something?

Comment: Hi, could you please explain me what do you mean by same class ?  Thanks